# Why would a report work in Pentaho Report Designer but not in BI Server

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence

I am building a report via Pentaho's Report designer.
I have a code/value table that provides values for a parameter used in the report. The value is shown in the dropdown, while the corresponding code is used as the filter in the backend sql query used to run the report.

In report designer, it runs perfectly.  When a value is selected, the SQL statement is executed with the code in place, and the report runs.

However, when I deploy the report into BI Server and attempt to run the report using the parameter, all values in the parameter show "bad value".

I have found no guidance on this, and was hoping someone might have seen this before and knows what to do.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the parameter for your report please uncheck the radio button of **validate parameter** and then again publish it to BI server. sometimes validating parameter causes problem in BI server.

I hope this will help for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input.  I have not heard anyone for nearly 3 weeks, and it was really frustrating me.  In the case of this parameter, I am using a code/value relationship where the value is what is in the parameter's drop down, and the code to ammend the SQL statement.  When I removed the validate parameter setting as you recommended, the value changed to the code, and the report froze. Do you have any other ideas that I can try?

Comment: to add to the fun of this question.  It's only doing this on some of the values in the drop down.  Others work perfectly.  Do I have a bad setting somewhere that is causing this?  Thanks